# Cognito Trigger Lambda cannot connect to Appsync, responds {"size":0,"timeout":0}

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cognito, aws-appsync

I have a lambda whose purpose is to ingest Cognito Post Confirmation events and use some of that event data to invoke a `createUser` mutation via AppSync. The lambda is receiving the following response from AppSync: `{"size":0,"timeout":0}`. I cannot find docs on what this means and the mutation does not occur; additionally, the same mutation and same credentials work fine from the AppSync console. Have I missed something obvious?

**Lambda**

```
const URL = require("url");
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const { CognitoIdentityServiceProvider } = require("aws-sdk");

const cognitoIdentityServiceProvider = new CognitoIdentityServiceProvider({
  apiVersion: "2016-04-18"
});
const initiateAuth = ({ clientId, userPoolId, username, password }) =>
  cognitoIdentityServiceProvider
    .adminInitiateAuth({
      AuthFlow: "ADMIN_NO_SRP_AUTH",
      AuthParameters: {
        USERNAME: username,
        PASSWORD: password
      },
      ClientId: clientId,
      UserPoolId: userPoolId
    })
    .promise();

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {
  console.log(event);
  const clientId = process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID;
  const userPoolId = process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID;
  const endPoint = process.env.APPSYNC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT;
  const username = process.env.COGNITO_USERNAME;
  const password = process.env.COGNITO_PASSWORD;
  const { AuthenticationResult } = await initiateAuth({
    clientId,
    userPoolId,
    username,
    password
  });
  const accessToken = AuthenticationResult && AuthenticationResult.AccessToken;
  console.log(`Access Token: ${accessToken}`);
  const postBody = {
    query: `mutation CreateUser($id: ID!, $username: String!) {
      createUser(input: {id: $id, username: $username}) {
        id,
        username
      }
    }`,
    operationName: "CreateUser",
    variables: {
      id: event.request.userAttributes.sub,
      username: event.username
    }
  };

  const uri = await URL.parse(endPoint);
  console.log(uri);

  const options = {
    method: "POST",
    body: JSON.stringify(postBody),
    headers: {
      host: uri.host,
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
      Authorization: accessToken
    }
  };
  const response = await fetch(uri.href, options);
  console.log(`AppSync mutation response: ${JSON.stringify(response)}`);
  const { data } = await response.json();

  const result = data && data.createUser;
  callback(null, result);
};
```

**SAM Template**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Stack for using Cognito events to create Users database. stack-ingest-cognito-events
Resources:
  IngestCognitoEventsLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName: role-ingest-cognito-events-lambda
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Principal:
            Service: lambda.amazonaws.com
          Action: sts:AssumeRole
      Policies:
      - PolicyName: policy-ingest-cognito-events-lambda
        PolicyDocument:
          Version: '2012-10-17'
          Statement:
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - logs:CreateLogGroup
            - logs:CreateLogStream
            - logs:PutLogEvents
            Resource: arn:aws:logs:*:*:*
          - Effect: Allow
            Action:
            - cognito-idp:Admin*
            Resource:
              Fn::Sub: arn:aws:cognito-idp:${AWS::Region}:${AWS::AccountId}:userpool/us-east-1_mypool
      ManagedPolicyArns:
      - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/service-role/AWSLambdaBasicExecutionRole
  IngestCognitoEventsLambda:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: lambda-ingest-cognito-events
      Description: Ingests Cognito events, propogates changes.
      AutoPublishAlias: live
      Runtime: nodejs8.10
      Handler: index.handler
      CodeUri: s3://mybucket
      MemorySize: 128
      Timeout: 10
      Environment:
        Variables:
          COGNITO_CLIENT_ID: myclientid
          COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID: us-east-1_mypool
          APPSYNC_GRAPHQL_ENDPOINT: https://myhash.appsync-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/graphql
          COGNITO_USERNAME: serviceAcctUsername
          COGNITO_PASSWORD: serviceAcctPassword
      Role:
        Fn::GetAtt:
        - IngestCognitoEventsLambdaRole
        - Arn
```

Comment: it would be easier to help if I had a request-id , region, and a timestamp so i can look our logs and tell you more. I mean AppSync request-id

Comment: I did not have AppSync logs turned on initially. Turned logs on, but found some issue with updating lambda via `sam deploy` when the lambda is manually configured to be a Cognito Trigger (to my knowledge, CloudFormation does not support Cognito Triggers); lambda was stuck in an Unsaved state. Disconnected the trigger, redeployed lambda, triggered a Test event and finally received error: "Calling the invoke API action failed with this message: The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda." Updated post above with the Lambda role. Thoughts?

Comment: If you're receiving this "The role defined for the function cannot be assumed by Lambda" you might want to check out the trust relationships.  In the role, go to "Trust Relationships" and make sure it has 

```"Principal": {
        "Service": "lambda.amazonaws.com"
      }```

As part of the trust relationship.

Comment: Yes, that is part of the Lambda's IAM permissions, which are in full above.

Comment: @VasileiosLekakis Resolved the IAM issues and performed a new test-fire of the lambda, same response of `{“size”:0,“timeout”:0}`. Here is the meta info: region is `us-east-1`, appsync request id is `34647431-285c-4952-a119-01eccd361e4f`, and timestamp is `2019-05-04T14:55:16.156Z`

Comment: It appears that the mutations are now flowing correctly, but I am still puzzled by that response.